# ListItem Index is always -1?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I ran some code where i needed to get the `ListItem` index, so i can pass that index into a separate `Fragment`. It wasn't working at first, so i set up a toast to check what index each item had like so...

```
songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // Getting list item index
            int songIndex = songView.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Index number : " + " " + songIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                

        }
    });
```

But for each item i click, i always end up with the `Index` as -1. Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Use the `position` parameter passed into that method.

Comment: You already have position defined for index. Use that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
int songIndex = position;
```

instead of

```
int songIndex = songView.getSelectedItemPosition();;
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `onItemClick` passes in a parameter `int position`. You use that instead of `getSelectedItemPosition()`. So your updated code would look like:

```
songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // Getting list item index
            int songIndex = position;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Index number : " + " " + songIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                

        }
    });
```